# Equivalency of Bounded Linear Functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove Ex 6d: 1a from Measure integration and Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler.

Suppose $V$ is a normed vector space and $\varphi$ is a linear functional on V. Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Prove

If $\varphi$ is a bounded linear functional then $\varphi^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a closed subset of $V$.

Proof:

Let $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a  limiting sequence with  $f_k\in \varphi^{-1}(\alpha)$. We know that $\varphi^{-1}(0)$ is closed when considering a bounded linear functional. Consider

$$\frac{f_k}{\alpha}-\frac{f_1}{\alpha}\in \text{Null}(\varphi).$$

Then

$$\frac{\lim f_k}{\alpha}-\frac{f_1}{\alpha}\in \text{Null}(\varphi).$$

Implying,

$$\varphi\left(\frac{\lim f_k}{\alpha}\right)=1$$.

That is,

$$\varphi(\lim f_k)=\alpha.$$

One can conclude that $\varphi^{-1}(\alpha)$ is closed. I am just doubting whether $\varphi(\lim f_k)=\alpha$, grants me that the limiting point of $\{f_k\}$ is in the set $\varphi^{-1}(\alpha)$ when I am not guaranteed that V is complete, i.e., $\lim f_k$ may not exist.

Comment: Your reasoning seems complicated. Assume $\varphi(f_k)=a$ and $f_k \rightarrow f.$ As $\varphi $ is bounded, i.e. continuous, hence $a=\varphi(f_k)\to \varphi(f).$ Hence $\varphi(f)=a.$ Another more abstract formulation is as follows:  by continuity of $\varphi$ the inverse image of any closed subset is closed. In particular  the inverse image of a number $a$ is closed in $X.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  I know this holds because R is Hausdorff and as such a singleton is closed so a continous mapping must imply that the inverse is closed.  I didn't want to go that route as the book does not make use of it in the chapter. Does the fact that $f$ may not be in the vector space, then $\varphi(f)$ may be undefined produce an issue.

Comment: I gave two proofs. You can rely on the first one.

Comment: Just realized that I need only consider sequences that converge to a point in the space of V  when determining if a set is closed.

Comment: Are you now confident you could answer this question yourself (so that it can also be marked as answered)?